# Different form key in template and controller

Tags: magento-1, login, form-key

When I am directly accessing customer/account/login page 
then, values for `$this->getRequest()->getParam('form_key');` and `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();` are different when I am checking in controller. 

But when I am going to login page by clicking login link on the website, then values for `$this->getRequest()->getParam('form_key');` and `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();` are same. 

It would be very helpful if any one faced similar issue or if someone can help me out to figure out and fix this issue.

Comment: did you checked for full page caching issue?

Comment: @Piyush FPC is not implemented.